# Meaning of $\overline{ab}$ in rings with unity

Tags: ring-theory, notation

> Let $R$ be a ring with unity. An element $x \in R$ is called $\textit{nilpotent}$ if $x^m = 0$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$. **a.)** Show that if $n=a^kb$ for some integers $a,b$, and $k$ where $k \neq 0$, then $\overline{ab}$ is a nilpotent element of $\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z}$.

The above question comes from Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra* (pg. 231). I do not have a question about how to solve this problem. Rather, I am wondering what the meaning of $\overline{ab}$ is as I have not seen this notation before. For context, a proof I found for this problem gives:

$$(ab)^k=(a^kb)b^{k-1}=nb^{k-1} \equiv 0 \mod n  \hspace{1cm} \blacksquare$$

But it is not at all clear to me what exactly $\overline{ab}$ means. Thanks for your time. **Note:** It's possible that this could be a notation specific to Dummit & Foote if anyone reading this is familiar with their textbook

Comment: Maybe equivalence class?

Comment: For $a\in\Bbb Z,$ [$\bar a=a+n\Bbb Z\in\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n)

Comment: For a ring $R$ and ideal $I$, $\bar{x}$ is a notation which is sometimes used for the coset $x+I$. In my opinion, most of the time this notation is unnecessary and leads to confusion. I try not to use it.

Comment: You can search here for this notation, and you will find that it is often used for elements in the factor ring. (I agree with Mark, that it is not very helpful), see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122023/prove-that-overlinex-is-nilpotent?rq=1), for example.

Comment: note that $a$ and $b$ are integers, not elements of any old ring, and they are writing $\overline{ab}$ for the image in the integers mod $n$.

Comment: @Mark Which notation do you prefer then?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Most of the time, just $x+I$. This notation is not that long for me to try to avoid it. Sometimes $x$ (mod $I$) can be useful as well. It depends of course on the context. I just saw people using $\bar{x}$ and then get confused about the difference between $x$ and $\bar{x}$. I also saw some professors use it when it was unnecessary. For example, the theorem about a polynomial $f\in F[x]$ having a root in some extension field confuses students even without new notations. In such proofs it's better to be as formal as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what edition you have, but I'm guessing in every edition it has something like this screenshot (which I grabbed from the 3rd edition.)[image: Page 8 of Dummit and Foote's abstract algebra book]

To find this I just consulted the index of the book...

Comment: I love what you are saying with the ... in the end of your answer 

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg [Ow my tongue!](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bite-tongue)

Comment: Well, you got me!